# Is it possible to pass data from li elements to the database using forms?

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I have this jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/w3vvL/157/

As you can see I have selected DVD's and unselected DVD's.

I would like to pass the unselected dvd's to my database but how should I do it?

```
How to request.getParamter("id");
```

where id=id of the li...

for li elements within a form?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. Instead of fading the element, you should move it between parents so you have only a single LI element on the whole page. Add a [hidden input field](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_hidden.asp) inside of it and set the name and value accordingly (name should allow you to locate the DVD in the database and value should tell you in which set it is).

These invisible form fields will be transmitted to the server when you submit the form.

Comment: problem in this case is I dont know how to get it in the hidden field....I have done form submission before with hidden fields.This is  kind of tedious for me...dont know how to get d ID of the each dv

Comment: Well, you know when you generate the LI element, don't you? Why not create the hidden element at the same time?

Comment: plz could jsfiddle it for me if you could?would be of great help

Comment: Sorry, your fiddle is missing all the vital information, namely how you distinguish between DVDs: There are no IDs, no names, nothing. You first need to fix this.

Comment: dats wat I m askin...Do i need to put ids for the li elements?will that help ?

Comment: Yes, that would help. Computers are notoriously bad at reading your mind :-) You need to make sure all the necessary information is available when you want to compute something. In your case, that means you need to generate unique IDs into the HTML. And when you do that, you can also generate `input` elements just like  Tilman Potthof suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden input field to do that.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="123"/>
```

Each element gets an hidden input and via jQuery or pure JavaScript you can disable the fields that should not be submitted.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="123" disabled="disabled"/>
```

Comment: but to get the id..Plz if u could show me on my example